# What knife kills count towards the Bloodthirsty Medal?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-2

I managed to get a Bloodthirsty Medal with four pistol kill and a single knife kill.  I was wondering, though, if I equip a Tactical Knife, does it count towards a medal if I knife someone with it?

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  It doesn't matter what weapon you use, as long as you get a 5 kill streak.  5 kills without dying.

Comment: see my question was about the challenge bloodthirsty count, Where you have to get 10 bloodthirsty medals. and I wasn't sure if i equipped the tac knife if it would count towards it or not

Comment: also the reaosn im asking is for the pistol specifically like i needed 2 more bloodthirsty medals and after the match ended i only needed one so i was wondering if i could just equip tac knife nand go ham wiht it

Answer (score 1):

I tried to get a bloodthirsty medal with the tactical knife -- it did not work.  The tactical attachment holds your combat knife at the ready, which I suppose makes sense.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The kills you get with the Tac knife go toward your gun that your using (Commenly pistols).  Since it counts as an attachment.